OpenAI API error: "Invalid parameter: 'response_format' of type 'json_schema' is not supported with model version `gpt-4-turbo`"
From the main page and official documentation, OpenAI clearly mentioned we can use the response_format as follows:

What I'm trying in Postman is the following:
{
    "instructions": "You are a personal math tutor. When asked a question, write and run Python code to answer the question.",
    "name": "Math Tutor",
    "tools": [{"type": "code_interpreter"}],
    "model": "GPT-4 Turbo",
    "type": "json_schema"
 }

But I got the following error:
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unknown parameter: 'type'.",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": "type",
        "code": "unknown_parameter"
    }
}

After asking some popular LLM models, they suggested to try the following in Postman:
{
    "instructions": "You are a personal math tutor. When asked a question, write and run Python code to answer the question.",
    "name": "Math_Tutor",
    "tools": [{"type": "code_interpreter"}],
    "model": "gpt-4-turbo",
    "response_format": {
        "type": "json_schema",
        "json_schema": {
            "strict": true,
            "name": "MathTutorResponse",
            "schema": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "result": {
                        "type": "number"
                    },
                    "explanation": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": ["result", "explanation"],
                "additionalProperties": false
            }
        }
    }
}

But I got the following error:
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid parameter: 'response_format' of type 'json_schema' is not supported with model version `gpt-4-turbo`.",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": "response_format",
        "code": null
    }
}

Am I missing anything here? Please provide me with a snippet where I can configure assistant output to be in JSON format.

apparently, it's not supported by gpt-4-turbo model, try gpt-4o instead.

You have confused two things:

getting OpenAI API response using JSON mode vs.
getting OpenAI API response using Structured Outputs.

As stated in the official OpenAI documentation:

Structured Outputs is the evolution of JSON mode. While both ensure
valid JSON is produced, only Structured Outputs ensure schema
adherance. Both Structured Outputs and JSON mode are supported in the
Chat Completions API, Assistants API, Fine-tuning API and Batch API.
We recommend always using Structured Outputs instead of JSON mode when
possible.
However, Structured Outputs with response_format: {type: "json_schema", ...} is only supported with the gpt-4o-mini,
gpt-4o-mini-2024-07-18, and gpt-4o-2024-08-06 model snapshots and
later.

While both use the response_format parameter, you enable them differently. See the table below on how to use them properly:




Structured Outputs
JSON mode




Outputs valid JSON
Yes
Yes


Adheres to schema
Yes (see supported schemas)
No


Compatible models
• gpt-4o-mini • gpt-4o-2024-08-06 and later
• gpt-3.5-turbo • gpt-4-* • gpt-4o-*


Enabling
response_format: { type: "json_schema", json_schema: {"strict": true, "schema": ...} }
response_format: { type: "json_object" }




You may also want to change the version of the OpenAI api, at least for me it was a blocker to not able to use structured outputs.
I changed env variable from 2024-03-01-preview to 2024-08-01-preview, and it worked.
